# Prevent italics after ".csv" in Latex

Tags: pdftex

This is what I have written in my Latex file:

```
Lists of generated file ".txt" were downloaded from the RCSB site, and the 'pdbesearch_3310382373986440321.csv' was  downloaded  from the PDBe site. %Fix the problem with the PDF after ".csv"

The ".txt" files contain a list of PDB IDs of all protein codes meeting the criteria. The 'pdbesearch_3310382373986440321.csv' contains PDB ID, Entity ID, Organism Scientific Name, Tax ID, Organism Synonyms, Rank (genus, subfamily, family, order, phylum, superkingdom), Genus, Experimente Data Available, Title, Entry Authors.
```

How do I prevent the italics after `.csv` as in the following screenshot? I have tried using `\\` and `\n` and other modificators but I haven't manage to prevent this:

[image: Problem]

Comment: I apologize. As you can see in the new edit. After the "....csv" plus text sections of the pictures, the text becomes italics and without space and one-lined. And I want to prevent that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with this code.

First, the error is a consequence of your use of an underscore in the file name: underscores are only valid in LaTeX in math mode (for whatever reason …) so LaTeX enters math mode which results in the italic text.

To prevent this, you should enter all file names as *verbatim* text in LaTeX (e.g. using `\verb`, or with the facilities provided by the `url` package).

Secondly, take a minute to think about typography: your quotation marks are inconsistent (you’re using both single and double quotation marks interchangeably), and you’re using straight quotation marks rather than typographically correct “curly” marks. If your keyboard doesn’t allow easily typing curly quotes, you can use ``` ``…'' ``` instead.

Lastly, the table in your screenshot. Read the documentation of the `booktabs` and implement the conventions for tables laid out therein.